# How can I import a certificate into the iOS keychain?

Tags: ios, swift, security, keychain

I tried the following code but I keep getting "The specified attribute does not exist" error. kSecValueRef was checked and is not nil

```
let attributes: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String : kSecClassCertificate,
                                 kSecValueRef as String : certificateRef!,
                                 kSecAttrApplicationTag as String : tag]

let osStatus = SecItemAdd(attributes as CFDictionary, nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the resource describing available attributes for the `kSecClassCertificate` type [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecclasscertificate).
You should change `kSecAttrApplicationTag` to `kSecAttrLabel`, that should solve the issue for you. The application tag is not a valid parameter for a certificate.

p.s. There is a document describing each of these attributes per class on the Apple developer documentation page, or you could also look at the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-57336.1.9/OSX/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecItemPriv.h.auto.html).